# Pytorch load weights

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, deep-copy

In many works, we can use this code to load pytorch model weights

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

But when the model have lots of parameters and sub-module, this way often does not work, I know there is a way to load: Using the OrderedDict just like:

```
for i, weigth in param_dict.items():
    use deepcopy function to save
```

And this way can also help us load a portion of the weights.
Could u please tell me how to write or give me an example, thank you!

Comment: *this way often does not work* what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: I always use the first variant and have not yet found any problems. Maybe you can explain the problem a bit more.